# Can't Update Plugin or add Javascript on Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: javascript, sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Hi why suddenly I can't update or add plugin and add javascript or update javascript in my 365 CRM. Yesterday I can do this without issue, but today when I try to add javascript.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Exception output:: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Unable to access availability database 'APJCRMLIVESG605_CONFIG' because the database replica is not in the PRIMARY or SECONDARY role. Connections to an availability database is permitted only when the database replica is in the PRIMARY or SECONDARY role. Try the operation again later.
```

It says database replica is not in the primary role or secondary role and to be primary role or secondary role. But I think I didn't change anything why this happen.

Comment: This was some kind of global outage. We had identical problems on our CRM instance. We raised a ticket and our instance has been fixed

Comment: yes thanks, its already works now